# HTML/Javascript passing key down event and another variable to a function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to observe cursor presses inside an input box.

I currently have the following code, but the function is never called.

```
<input type="Text" onkeydown ="CheckCursor(event,'abcd')" />

function CheckCursor(e, boxName)
{
    alert(e.keyCode + ' and box was: '+boxname);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3jfqwrf5/2/

Why is the function never called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. You've used the JSFiddle option "wrap code in onload event" (the default), so the `CheckCursor` function is not in the global scope, so can't be accessed as the event handler.  You get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CheckCursor is not defined

You need to specify it as "no wrap" instead.  The option is over on the left hand side.

2. When the above is fixed, your parameter/variable names don't match:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: boxname is not defined

You have `boxname` and `boxName`, JavaScript is a case sensitive language.

[Here's a fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jfqwrf5/4/).